# Fastlane git_commit action - skip if there is nothing to commit

Tags: git, version-control, automation, fastlane

I use the [git_commit action](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/git_commit/):

> git_commit(path: "*", message: "message")

This action fails if there is nothing to commit. How can I continue executing my Fastlane script even if there is nothing to commit?

What I'm looking for could be accomplished with the any of the two options:

1. Add some parameter to the `git_commit` action so it would not crash the script if there is nothing to commit (but rather, continue)
2. Check if there are any changes and only then invoke `git_commit`.

I didn't find any way to get this done using method 1, so **I'm looking for an implementation with the second approach.**

Answer (score 4):

You could try asserting that the status is clean, catching an exception, and handling it via a git commit:

```
begin
  ensure_git_status_clean
rescue
  git_commit
end
```

Alternatively you can use the `sh` action to do whatever you want in the shell

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a script that tells you whether there are staged changes and then use the output to determine whether you should create a commit.

The following script returns 1 if there's any staged changes, 0 otherwise.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -n "$(git diff --name-only --cached)" ]]
then
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi
```

Assuming you name the script *CheckStagedFiles*, you would have to add the following to your lane:

```
shouldCommit = sh(".CheckStagedFiles.sh")
if shouldCommit
    git_commit(path: "*", message: "message")
end
```